# Import Module in sys.path is not found

Tags: python, import, module, path

I have a module that I use in a number of scripts. Its path is `C:\PYTHONprojects\utilities\utility_module.py` There is an (empty) file called `__init__.py` in the same folder.

If I import the module inside the PyCharm environment, it works fine:
`import utility_module as um` but if do the same from the Python command line, I get:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utility_module'`

But the folder *is* in the PATH:
From the windows command line:
    In: PATH

```
Out: 
......
C:\PYTHONprojects\utilities; C:\PYTHONprojects
.....
```

or from the Python Command Line:

```
In: import sys
    sys.path

Out:
    ......
    'C:\\PYTHONprojects', 'C:\\PYTHONprojects\\utilities'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to load your module, it needs to be part of your `PYTHONPATH` system env (not `PATH`) or `sys.path`.

Your pycharm loads the working directory into your path for you. When you do that on command line, you need to take care for that.

So either add your project folder to system env `PYTHONPATH` or before you load the module, execute this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\PYTHONprojects\utilities')
```

Comment: This gives me: `Attribute Error: module 'ntpath' has no atribute 'append'`

Comment: @doctorer my bad, I meant `sys` module not `os`. I updated my answer